# Is there a DRY way to do this?

Tags: javascript

I have the following [heavily snipped] code:

```
data = {};
data['someradio'] = '2';

for(key in data)
{
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key))
    {
        if(key == 'someradio')
        {
            document.getElementById(key + '1').checked = data[key] == '1' ? true : false;
            document.getElementById(key + '2').checked = data[key] == '2' ? true : false;
            document.getElementById(key + '3').checked = data[key] == '3' ? true : false;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to condense the 3 `document.` lines in to 1?

There are actually 12 (not 3) recurrences of this line, with only the number changed.

Comment: Of course. Use a loop, and concatenate the loop counter, like `key + i`. Also, you can get rid of the inner `if` by using `&& key == 'someradio'` in the first `if` condition, and you can shorten the `.checked` assignment to `.checked = data[key] == i`.

Comment: `if(key == 'someradio')` so you're iterating over an object to find a particular key? Why not use `data.someradio` instead?

Comment: When x is boolean, replace `x ? true : false` with `x`. If you just want to booleanize an expression, use not twice.  `!! (3 -3)` is `false`.

Comment: @amnotiam Ah, of course! Mind went blank... that's what I get for working at 5am! RE: using `&& key == 'someradio'`, this is actually part of a much larger `switch`. Nice point on shortening the `.checked` assignment; I'd never tried doing that before.

Comment: @zerkms It's actually part of a much larger `switch`, with a `default` handling for most `key`s, but `case`s for some edge-cases ;)

Comment: If I was a smart-ass, (and I'm not), I would just suggest deleting the white-space.  Boom!  One line!

Comment: @Dan - I guess you think that would be nicer... Sorry, couldn't resist ;)

Comment: Wait.. that `for..if..if` loop is not necessary. It's actually doing just this: `if (data.hasOwnProperty("someradio")) ..`. The for loop is useless. Also, technically `hasOwnProperty` is unnecessary if you're simply using an object literal and not inheriting from anything else (unless you've modified the Object object)

Comment: @JosephSilber Hey, your unwarranted preferential treatment of `while` loops just goes to show that truly, "beauty is in the eye of the beholder."

Comment: @slebetman As mentioned, this function is a lot bigger IRL. I've just snipped the code down to relevant parts. All of the lines are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {};
data['someradio'] = '2';

for(key in data)
{
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key))
    {
        if(key == 'someradio')
        { 
            for (var i = 1; i <= 3 /*put desired value there */; i++) {
               document.getElementById(key + i).checked = data[key] == i ? true : false;            
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var counter = 13;

while ( --counter ) {
    document.getElementById(key + counter).checked = data[key] == counter;
}
```

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - Your way would have `counter` be 11 within the block the first time it runs...

Comment: If you're going to declare a counter variable and use it as the loop condition, you may as well just use a for loop.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - How would that be any different?

Comment: @Dan, Blender - That's all a matter of opinion. I hate `for` loops. *They look ugly*.

Comment: @JosephSilber - Sorry, just disregard what I said... kind of sleepy right now.

Comment: @JosephSilber They do not.  LOL.  To each his own I guess.  LOL.

Answer (score 1):

Well here's one cheaper way:

```
data = {};
data['someradio'] = '2';

var key = 'someradio';
var p;
if (p = data[key]) {
    for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        document.getElementById(key + i).checked = (i == p);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JbpBx/

Comment: jQuery most definitely *does not* have `hasOwnProperty` built into [`$.each`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.each).

Comment: Loading jQuery just to use an iterator would be... odd.

Comment: @JosephSilber You're right I should clarify what I meant - he seemed to be using it to ensure the property was one assigned, not a built-in property. The way jQuery loops through objects gets you that functionality for free. But it's moot anyway since it wasn't necessary to do what he was asking.